Flet update icon in async
I have problem with flet updating icon, self.value is updating perfect but why icon does not changing at the start of class it adds icon ft.icons.SIGNAL_WIFI_STATUSBAR_NULL_OUTLINED but in async it does not updating in interface
import asyncio
import flet as ft
import requests
import time

class Countdown(ft.Text):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.running = False
        self.value = "Connecting..."
        self.icon = ft.Icon(ft.icons.SIGNAL_WIFI_STATUSBAR_NULL_OUTLINED)

    def did_mount(self):
        self.running = True
        self.update()
        self.page.run_task(self.update_timer)

    def will_unmount(self):
        self.running = False

    async def update_timer(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                requests.get("http://www.google.com", timeout=3)
                self.value = "Connected"
                self.icon = ft.Icon(ft.icons.WIFI)
                self.chiconke()
                self.update()
                print(self.icon)
            except requests.ConnectionError:
                self.value = "Disconnected"
                self.icon = ft.icons.WIFI
                self.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

def create_statusbar():
    countdown = Countdown()

    return ft.Container(
        content=ft.Row(
            [
                ft.CupertinoListTile(
                    bgcolor_activated=ft.colors.AMBER_ACCENT,
                    leading=countdown.icon,
                    title=countdown,
                    width=180,
                ),

                ft.CupertinoListTile(  # Example: API status
                    bgcolor_activated=ft.colors.AMBER_ACCENT,
                    leading=ft.Icon(name=ft.icons.API),
                    title=ft.Text(countdown.icon),
                    subtitle=ft.Text("Checking..."),  # Placeholder for dynamic update
                    width=150,
                ),

                ft.CupertinoListTile(  # Example: API status
                    bgcolor_activated=ft.colors.AMBER_ACCENT,
                    leading=ft.Icon(name=ft.icons.API),
                    title=ft.Text("API Status"),
                    subtitle=ft.Text("Checking..."),  # Placeholder for dynamic update
                    width=150,
                ),

                ft.CupertinoListTile(  # Example: API status
                    bgcolor_activated=ft.colors.AMBER_ACCENT,
                    leading=ft.Icon(name=ft.icons.API),
                    title=ft.Text("API Status"),
                    subtitle=ft.Text("Checking..."),  # Placeholder for dynamic update
                    width=150,
                ),
            ],
        ),
        border=ft.border.all(1, ft.colors.GREY_700),
        border_radius=ft.border_radius.all(10),
    )

I have tried everything, async updates text but not icon.

Flet Text doesn't take an icon (you can find the full list of things it looks for here), so while you can store it as a property it won't be displayed. If you want to display an icon in line with that Text, wrap it in a row and put an Icon in as well
class Countdown(ft.Row):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.running = False
        self.text = ft.Text("Connecting...")
        self.icon = ft.Icon(ft.icons.SIGNAL_WIFI_STATUSBAR_NULL_OUTLINED)
        self.controls = [self.icon, self.text]

    def did_mount(self):
        self.running = True
        self.update()
        self.page.run_task(self.update_timer)

    def will_unmount(self):
        self.running = False

    async def update_timer(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                requests.get("http://www.google.com", timeout=3)
                self.text = "Connected"
                self.icon = ft.Icon(ft.icons.WIFI)
                self.chiconke()
                self.update()
                print(self.icon)
            except requests.ConnectionError:
                self.text = "Disconnected"
                self.icon = ft.Icon(ft.icons.WIFI)
                self.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

# continue your code

The row will need styling, but that should display both the text and the icon side by side
